# Selenium webdriver JavaScript not able to click on link

Tags: javascript, selenium, mocha.js

```
<a id="compareCompanies" b:onclick="needsController.showQuotes = true;" href="#">Compare companies</a>
```

Selenium Webdriver JavaScript code using Mocha:

```
driver.wait(function () {
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("compareCompanies"));
}, 5000);

var compareCompaniesLink = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("compareCompanies"));

compareCompaniesLink.click();
```

Error I get is:

> NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: {"method":"CSS
>   selector","selector":"*[id=\"compareCompanies\"]"}

Answer (score 0):

Seems like error is here:

Original:

```
var compareCompaniesLink = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("compareCompanies"));
```

Updated:

```
var compareCompaniesLink = driver.findElement(By.id("compareCompanies"));
```

Comment: Using JavaScript and Mocha:    test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
    webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'); var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
        usingServer(phantom.address()).withCapabilities({ "browserName": "phantomjs" }).
        build();